# The application crashes when using pybind11 in other thread(using QThread)

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, qt, pybind11

I have embedded module with class:

```cpp
PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(appmodule, m) {

    py::class_<Camera>(m, "Camera")
            .def(py::init<>())
            .def("onFrameEvent", &Camera::onFrameEvent, pybind11::call_guard<pybind11::gil_scoped_release>());
}
```

As stated in the documentation, when working with multithreading, I added `pybind11::call_guard<pybind11::gil_scoped_release>()`.

Next, I have a class inheriting QThread with an overloaded `run()` method:

```cpp
class Worker : public QThread {

        Q_OBJECT

        public:
            Worker(Camera* cam);
            void run();

        private:
            Camera* camera;
    };
```

```cpp
void Worker::run() {

    // Next code runs in other thread:

    QTimer* loop = new QTimer();
    connect(loop, &QTimer::timeout, [=]() {
        cv::Mat m = camera->getOpenCVMat();
        py::array_t<uint8_t> output(
                py::buffer_info(
                        m.data,
                        sizeof(uint8_t),
                        py::format_descriptor<uint8_t>::format(),
                        3,
                        std::vector<size_t> {static_cast<unsigned long>(m.rows), static_cast<unsigned long>(m.cols), 3},
                        std::vector<size_t> { sizeof(uint8_t) * static_cast<unsigned long>(m.cols) * 3, sizeof(uint8_t) * 3, sizeof(uint8_t)}));
    
        camera->getPythonHandle().attr("onFrameEvent")(output); // Call event on python side
    });
    
    loop->start(1000);


    QThread::exec();
}
```

On python side:

```py
import appmodule
import cv2


class MyCamera(appmodule.Camera):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def onFrameEvent(self, image):
        cv2.imshow('', image)
```

To initialize the interpreter, I use `py::initialize_interpreter();` at the start of `main()` function.

The problem is that the application crashes with the following message:

> pybind11::handle::inc_ref() is being called while the GIL is either
> not held or invalid. Please see
> https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/misc.html#common-sources-of-global-interpreter-lock-errors
> for debugging advice.
>
> If you are convinced there is no bug in your
> code, you can #define PYBIND11_NO_ASSERT_GIL_HELD_INCREF_DECREFto
> disable this check. In that case you have to ensure this #define is
> consistently used for all translation units linked into a given
> pybind11 extension, otherwise there will be ODR violations.The failing
> pybind11::handle::inc_ref() call was triggered on a function object.
>
> pybind11::handle::dec_ref() is being called while the GIL is either
> not held or invalid. Please see
> https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/misc.html#common-sources-of-global-interpreter-lock-errors
> for debugging advice. If you are convinced there is no bug in your
> code, you can #define PYBIND11_NO_ASSERT_GIL_HELD_INCREF_DECREFto
> disable this check. In that case you have to ensure this #define is
> consistently used for all translation units linked into a given
> pybind11 extension, otherwise there will be ODR violations.The failing
> pybind11::handle::dec_ref() call was triggered on a function object.
>
> libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type
> std::runtime_error: pybind11::handle::dec_ref() PyGILState_Check()
> failure.

When trying to define PYBIND11_NO_ASSERT_GIL_HELD_INCREF_DECREF, the crash does not disappear, but only this is displayed in the message:

> libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: pybind11::handle::dec_ref() PyGILState_Check() failure.

I also tried to add `py::gil_scoped_release release;` at the start of `run()` method, but it didn't fix the problem

System: MacOS Ventura

Answer (score 1):

you need to acquire the GIL inside your lambda (thread) before you start manipulating python objects.

```cpp
connect(loop, &QTimer::timeout, [=]() {
py::gil_scoped_acquire guard{}
...
});
```

Comment: Now it gives me 
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: The interpreter is already running

Comment: @MHDtA had the wrong type in there, it should be `gil_scoped_acquire`.

Comment: Now my thread just freezes on this line. I tried to make a ```pybind11::gil_scoped_release release{};``` before ```worker->start();```, but it didn't help

Comment: @MHDtA now we know the GIL is being held by another thread, so you'll have to figure that out from the rest of the code.

Comment: Can I create independent interpreter for each thread? That would really solve my problem.

Comment: @MHDtA not before python 3.12 where we get per interpreter GIL, right now you will have to drop the GIL from whoever is holding it.